# How to authenticate a HTTP request to an OrientDB function on AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, httprequest, orientdb

I have the following OrientDB function:

```
http://localhost:2480/function/Application/getPassFailCount/9:600
```

And it returns the following JSON result:

```
{"result":[{"@type":"d","@version":0,"pass":16.0,"fail":2.0,"@fieldTypes":"pass=d,fail=d"}]}
```

What I need to do is to get the values of `"pass"` and `"fail"` to use in my web page.

So far I have done this with AngularJS:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:2480/function/Application/getPassFailCount/9:600').
success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data.result;



//    $scope.passCount = ;
//    $scope.failCount = ;

});
```

Currently it gives the error "401 Unauthorized". How do I authenticate the request?

And if possible, can anyone give some tips on how to get the `passCount` and `failCount`  from the JSON result returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [OrientDB HTTP API documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/1.7.8/orientdb.wiki/OrientDB-REST.html) states that you have to use HTTP Basic authentication for issuing commands. That means you have to include an `Authorization` header along with your request.

There are a few ways to achieve this, here is a simpler one. Use the configuration object parameter for `$http.get` to set the header on the request:

```
function base64(str) {
    return btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
}

$http.get('http://...', {
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64(user + ':' + password) }
}).success(...);
```

You should definitely move all your database logic to an Angular service, so you can keep this code in one place instead of polluting your controllers.

To make it even cleaner, you could look into [$http interceptors](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) and write a request interceptor that adds the header to *every* HTTP call.

---

Regarding the JSON question: you can see that the result object contains an array with a single element. Use indexing to get the actual record.

```
var result = data.result[0];
$scope.passCount = result.pass;
$scope.failCount = result.fail;
```

If you wrote a service as I mentioned, you could hide this implementation detail from your controller.

```
function getCount() {
    return $http.get(...).then(function (data) {
        var result = data.result[0];

        // the caller will only see this simpler object
        return { pass: result.pass, fail: result.fail };
    });
}
```

Comment: Woah! You're a lifesaver! Thanks loads!