# How to use OrientDB schema modelling?

Tags: angular, model, orientdb

I use OrientDB and Angular 2.

I want to use model, but I don't know how to use `@rid` in model when http request is made.

```
getAll() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>('/api/users');
}

export class User {
    rid: string; 
    username: string;
    password: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to authenticate a HTTP request to an OrientDB function on AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117149/how-to-authenticate-a-http-request-to-an-orientdb-function-on-angularjs)

Comment: i want import rid to model. its startwith @ in json data

Comment: Hi @ekonovich, which version of orientdb are you using?

Comment: it was solved. i use now version 3,0